# Compatibility between Windows Phone 7.1 - 7.8 apps and Windows Phone 8 devices

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7.1.1, windows-phone-7.8

Do Windows Phone 7.1 - 7.8 apps run reasonably well on Windows Phone 8 devices?
Is there any reason in terms of compatibility for me to choose one over the other?

Comment: Note that WP 7.1 is the OS version and was being marketed as WP 7.5 (Mango). 7.8 was an update to bring new tile sizes among other things. So for now there are only two targets: 7.1 and 8.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find the official documentation about WP 7.1 and WP 8 platform compatibility in the following link:

[App platform compatibility for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206947%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Although in general any WP7 app will run without problem in a WP 8 device, this documentation addresses some cases where the behavior may be different.

So, if you don't use any specific features introduced in WP 8, you can develop targetting WP 7.1. That way your app will be available for more people. If you want to take advantage of WP 8 specific features such as NFC or Nokia maps, I would recommend to develop for both platforms, reusing as much code as you can.

Answer (score 1):

You can run Windows phone 7 apps on a device with Windows phone 8, but not vice versa. I'd advocate targeting 7.x, unless you need to use 8.x specific hardware like NFC, in which case, I'd advocate targeting specific versions.

Comment: A potential contradiction between your answer and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18065962/175036

Comment: @Skúli That's talking about developing for Windows Phone 8 on Windows 7 (desktop). You have to be running Windows 8, and have a processor capable of SLAT to run the Windows Phone 8 SDK and all the tools for debugging.

Comment: Ok. Guess we are talking about slightly different things. My question is maybe a little unexact. As long as I can make programs that are runnable reasonably well on Windows Phone 8, even if it does not have the Windows Phone 8 style, I'm happy for now.

Comment: Well, I'm answerignt he question about whether an app targetting WP7.x will work on WP8.x; Jim has answered your other question about installing the development tools on your PC to actually do it.

Comment: So I can't do what you talk about, using Windows 7? I'm feeling confused.

Comment: At the risk of answering your other question here: It is possible to create apps for WP7.x on Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2010 (there's even a free express edition). These apps will work on devices running Windows Phone 8. Windows 8 is required to develop apps targetting (only) WP8.x

Comment: I'm confused. Can I make 'a program by using Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010' that will run on 'Windows Phone 8'?